# Postfix receives email but doesn't send [new to server management]

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server, plesk

As the title suggest, I'm struggling to get the mail server to send emails.

I recently purchased a VPS for hosting and I'm currently trying to set up the mail server which can now receive emails but still not send them.

This is my postfix main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mail.aperturedesigns.uk
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydomain = aperturedesigns.uk
virtual_mailbox_domains = $virtual_mailbox_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual_domains
virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps, hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/vmailbox
transport_maps = , hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/transport
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_use_tls = no
smtpd_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_proxy_timeout = 3600s
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/blacklists, permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated
authorized_flush_users =
authorized_mailq_users =
smtp_send_xforward_command = yes
smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/qmail/mailnames
virtual_uid_maps = static:30
virtual_gid_maps = static:31
smtpd_milters = , inet:127.0.0.1:12768
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/var/spool/postfix/plesk/sdd_transport_maps
virtual_transport = plesk_virtual
plesk_virtual_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
message_size_limit = 10240000
virtual_mailbox_limit = 0
recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:127.0.0.1:12346
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient,header_recipient
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
tls_medium_cipherlist = HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
```

Bearing in mind I am extremely new to server management and probably should learn a bit more before attempting a task like this, does anyone have an idea what I might have done wrong?

TIA

UPDATE:

Here is my mail log as suggested:

```
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost check-quota[11773]: Starting the check-quota filter...
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost plesk sendmail[11772]: handlers_stderr: SKIP
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost plesk sendmail[11772]: SKIP during call 'check-quota' handler
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost postfix/pickup[6003]: 83981800DC: uid=0 from=<root>
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost postfix/cleanup[11777]: 83981800DC: message-id=<20190413062845.83981800DC@mail.aperturedesigns.uk>
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost postfix/qmgr[2097]: 83981800DC: from=<root@localhost.localdomain>, size=1061, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[11778]: warning: do not list domain localhost.localdomain in BOTH mydestination and virtual_alias_domains
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[11778]: warning: do not list domain localhost.localdomain in BOTH mydestination and virtual_alias_domains
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost postfix/local[11781]: 83981800DC: to=<root@localhost.localdomain>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.03, delays=0.02/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Apr 13 06:28:45 localhost postfix/qmgr[2097]: 83981800DC: removed
Apr 13 06:31:27 localhost postfix/qmgr[2097]: A5DAC7F861: from=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, size=885, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 06:31:57 localhost postfix/smtp[11786]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.167.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 06:31:57 localhost postfix/smtp[11786]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c00::1b]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 06:32:27 localhost postfix/smtp[11786]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-
in.l.google.com[74.125.205.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 06:32:57 localhost postfix/smtp[11786]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 06:32:57 localhost postfix/smtp[11786]: A5DAC7F861: to=<mconie95@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=28083, delays=27993/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-
in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr 13 07:41:27 localhost postfix/qmgr[2097]: A5DAC7F861: from=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, size=885, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 07:41:57 localhost postfix/smtp[12548]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.76.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 07:41:57 localhost postfix/smtp[12548]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 07:42:27 localhost postfix/smtp[12548]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.205.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 07:42:27 localhost postfix/smtp[12548]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c02::1a]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 07:42:57 localhost postfix/smtp[12548]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Conn
ection timed out
Apr 13 07:42:57 localhost postfix/smtp[12548]: A5DAC7F861: to=<mconie95@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=32283, delays=32192/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr 13 08:51:27 localhost postfix/qmgr[2097]: A5DAC7F861: from=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, size=885, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 08:51:57 localhost postfix/smtp[12987]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.194.76.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 08:51:57 localhost postfix/smtp[12987]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 08:52:27 localhost postfix/smtp[12987]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.205.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 08:52:27 localhost postfix/smtp[12987]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c02::1b]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 08:52:57 localhost postfix/smtp[12987]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 08:52:57 localhost postfix/smtp[12987]: A5DAC7F861: to=<mconie95@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=36483, delays=36393/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr 13 10:01:27 localhost postfix/qmgr[2097]: A5DAC7F861: from=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, size=885, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 10:01:57 localhost postfix/smtp[13454]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.167.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 10:01:57 localhost postfix/smtp[13454]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c0a::1b]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 10:02:27 localhost postfix/smtp[13454]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.205.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 10:02:27 localhost postfix/smtp[13454]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c02::1b]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 10:02:57 localhost postfix/smtp[13454]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 10:02:57 localhost postfix/smtp[13454]: A5DAC7F861: to=<mconie95@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=40683, delays=40593/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr 13 11:11:27 localhost postfix/qmgr[2097]: A5DAC7F861: from=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, size=885, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 11:11:57 localhost postfix/smtp[13957]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.167.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 11:11:57 localhost postfix/smtp[13957]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c00::1a]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 11:12:27 localhost postfix/smtp[13957]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.205.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 11:12:27 localhost postfix/smtp[13957]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c02::1a]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 11:12:57 localhost postfix/smtp[13957]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 11:12:57 localhost postfix/smtp[13957]: A5DAC7F861: to=<mconie95@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=44883, delays=44793/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr 13 11:19:42 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=139.162.109.245, lip=77.68.29.49, session=<hQKHmGeGGqyLom31>
Apr 13 12:04:00 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=196.52.43.62, lip=77.68.29.49, TLS handshaking: Connection closed, session=<kAn1NmiGs/TENCs+>
Apr 13 12:21:27 localhost postfix/qmgr[2097]: A5DAC7F861: from=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, size=885, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 12:21:57 localhost postfix/smtp[14445]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.167.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 12:21:57 localhost postfix/smtp[14445]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c00::1a]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 12:22:27 localhost postfix/smtp[14445]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.205.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 12:22:27 localhost postfix/smtp[14445]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4010:c02::1a]:25: No route to host
Apr 13 12:22:57 localhost postfix/smtp[14445]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 12:22:57 localhost postfix/smtp[14445]: A5DAC7F861: to=<mconie95@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=49083, delays=48993/0.01/90/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.68.27]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr 13 12:25:52 localhost dovecot: pop3-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 1 secs): user=<>, rip=198.108.66.208, lip=77.68.29.49, TLS, session=<MiAnhWiGxGvGbELQ>
Apr 13 12:56:22 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, method=CRAM-MD5, rip=86.22.6.100, lip=77.68.29.49, mpid=14684, TLS, session=<gGI38miG/N5WFgZk>
Apr 13 12:56:23 localhost postfix/smtpd[14685]: connect from keeper-us-east-1c.mxtoolbox.com[18.205.72.90]
Apr 13 12:56:25 localhost postfix/smtpd[14685]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from keeper-us-east-1c.mxtoolbox.com[18.205.72.90]: 554 5.7.1 <test@mxtoolboxsmtpdiag.com>: Relay access denied; from=<supertool@mxtoolbox.com> to=<test@mxtoolboxsmtpdiag.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<keeper-us-east-1c.mxtoolbox.com>
Apr 13 12:56:26 localhost /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[731]: Message aborted.
Apr 13 12:56:26 localhost /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/psa-pc-remote[731]: Message aborted.
Apr 13 12:56:26 localhost postfix/smtpd[14685]: disconnect from keeper-us-east-1c.mxtoolbox.com[18.205.72.90] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Apr 13 12:57:09 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, method=CRAM-MD5, rip=86.22.6.100, lip=77.68.29.49, mpid=14744, TLS, session=<nikF9WiGH99WFgZk>
Apr 13 12:57:09 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, method=CRAM-MD5, rip=86.22.6.100, lip=77.68.29.49, mpid=14746, TLS, session=<AgwK9WiGIN9WFgZk>
Apr 13 12:57:10 localhost dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<admin@aperturedesigns.uk>, method=CRAM-MD5, rip=86.22.6.100, lip=77.68.29.49, mpid=14748, TLS, session=<3xIY9WiGId9WFgZk>
Apr 13 12:59:46 localhost postfix/anvil[14687]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:18.205.72.90) at Apr 13 12:56:23
Apr 13 12:59:46 localhost postfix/anvil[14687]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:18.205.72.90) at Apr 13 12:56:23
Apr 13 12:59:46 localhost postfix/anvil[14687]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Apr 13 12:56:23
Apr 13 13:07:19 localhost postfix/smtpd[14890]: connect from cpc92102-nrte30-2-0-cust99.8-4.cable.virginm.net[86.22.6.100]
```

Comment: Check the mail log.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added the mail log and noticed it had a warning. I'm not sure if this would affect it but I also noticed that when trying to connect to gmail servers it times out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact your VPS provider. They have blocked outgoing mail on your server.

Comment: I contacted my provider and it turns out they had a 30 day block on new registrants for outing mail. They have since unblocked this for me. Thank you for your help.